# Sqlite insert in Flask

Tags: python, sqlite, flask, jinja2

I have an html template that includes some Python code and HTML templates. This is a sample below.

Python:

```
cur1 = g.db.execute('select ID from Students')
students = [dict(ID=row[0]) for row in cur1.fetchall()]
cur2 = g.db.execute('select ID from Quizzes')
quizzes = [dict(ID=row[0]) for row in cur2.fetchall()]
if request.method == 'POST':
    if not session.get('logged_in'):
        abort(401)
    g.db.execute('insert into Results (quiz,student,grade) values '\
                 '(?,?,?)',[request.form['Quiz'],
                            request.form['Student'],
                            request.form['grade']])
    g.db.commit()
    return render_template('add_result.html',students=students,quizzes=quizzes)
```

HTML:

```
  <form action="{{ url_for('add_result') }}" method=post>
  <select name="Quiz">
    {% for quiz in quizzes %}
    <option value="{{ quiz }}">{{ quiz.ID }}</option>
    {% endfor %}
  </select>
  <select name="Student">
    {% for student in students %}
    <option value="{{ student }}">{{ student.ID }}</option>
    {% endfor %}
  </select>
  <input type="number" name="grade">
  <input type="submit" value=Submit>
  </form>
```

which outputs the drop down lists in the format I want (integers), however, for example, say the values quiz #1 and student #1 with a grade of 100, they are then input into SQLite as

> (2, u"{'ID': 1}", u"{'ID': 1}", 100.0)

How can I get this output?:

> (2,1,1,100.0)

Comment: Where do you want "this output" to appear? What specific code are you trying to improve?

Comment: @amccormack I am just trying to have them entered into the database in that format. I am trying to improve the g.db.execute statement

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was in the HTML:

```
<select name="Quiz">
    {% for quiz in quizzes %}
    <option value="{{ quiz }}">{{ quiz.ID }}</option>
    {% endfor %}
  </select>
  <select name="Student">
    {% for student in students %}
    <option value="{{ student }}">{{ student.ID }}</option>
    {% endfor %}
```

I had "quiz" and "student" as the s, with quiz.ID and student.ID appearing as text in the values. It is the option value that gets returned by the form.

It should be:

```
  <select name="Quiz">
    {% for quiz in quizzes %}
    <option value="{{ quiz.ID }}">{{ quiz.ID }}</option>
    {% endfor %}
  </select>
  <select name="Student">
    {% for student in students %}
    <option value="{{ student.ID }}">{{ student.ID }}</option>
    {% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to convert the values to the right type before sending them to the database.  The `request.form` dict provides a [`get`](http://werkzeug.pocoo.org/docs/0.10/datastructures/#werkzeug.datastructures.TypeConversionDict.get) method that will convert values or raises an error.

```
g.db.execute(
    'insert into Results (quiz,student,grade) values (?,?,?)',
    (
        request.form.get('Quiz', type=int),
        request.form.get('Student', type=int),
        request.form.get('grade', type=float)
    )
)
```

It would be much easier (and safer) in the long run to use a form library such as [Flask-WTF](https://flask-wtf.readthedocs.org/) to parse, convert, and validate the data for you.  Also consider using an ORM such as [Flask-SQLAlchemy](http://flask-sqlalchemy.pocoo.org/) rather than writing raw SQL statements.